# How to calculate t-statistic for portfolio

Tags: statistics, finance

I recently did a portfolio sort. I had following data:

```
Time FIRM return size
  1  1       0.2   5
  2  1       0.1   6
  1  2       0.1   7
  2  2       0.1   8
  .  .         .   .
  .  .         .   .
  .  .         .   .
```

Every month I sorted the date according to their size into 5 buckets (p1..p5) and calculated the average return of each bucket, giving me:

```
Time p1  p2    p3   p4   p5    p5-p1
 1  0.5  0.4  0.3  0.2   0.1   -0.4
 2  0.5  0.4  0.3  0.2   0.1   -0.4
 3   .    .    .    .    .      .
 4   .    .    .    .    .      .
 5   .    .    .    .    .      .
```

In the end I calculate the Average return of each bucket:

```
 p1  p2    p3   p4   p5    p5-p1
0.5  0.4  0.3  0.2   0.1   -0.4
```

Now, I want to know if these average return and especially if p5-p1 is statistically significant. Do you guys have an idea how I could do this?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).  To [include a table in a question](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4240/290189), you may click the linked post.

Comment: If you want to determine whether populations 1 and 2 have significantly different means (medians), then use _original_ (not grouped) data from those two populations. If both samples seem normal, then compare means using a Welch t test. If obviously not normal (e.g, skewed with many remarkable outliers) then use Wilcoxon rank sum test to compare medians. In your case, information is needlessly lost in binning because you have access to the original data. // If comparing $g > 2$ populations, use one-sample ANOVA (normal) or Kruskal-Wallis (nonnormal).